# Combine elements after concatenating in XSLT transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to transform this portion of my code :

```
                     <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
                            <LineList>
                                <Line>
                                    <Numb>7103410047036</Numb>
                                    <Quantity>543</Quantity>
                                </Line>
                                <Line>
                                    <Numb>7103410047069</Numb>
                                    <Quantity>476</Quantity>
                                </Line>
                                <Line>
                                    <Numb>7103410047912</Numb>
                                    <Quantity>494</Quantity>
                                </Line>
                                <Line>
                                    <Numb>7103410047128</Numb>
                                    <Quantity>973</Quantity>
                                </Line>
                                <Line>
                                    <Numb>7103410047184</Numb>
                                    <Quantity>1209</Quantity>
                                </Line>
                            </LineList>
```

TO this portion in XML:

```
                            <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
                            <Item>7103410047</Item>
```

ie. Chop off last three digits - combine all identical Numbs and insert into one Item Element in the transformed XML. I am new to XSLT - ie this is my first try - I have read functions such as those located here : http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp and http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_concat.html

My XSLT :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item"> <!--here is where I am transforming-->
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:value-of select=
"concat(Sku)
"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="address/node()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is my first attempt at a declarative language and I would appreciate any guidance even if the code is not answered

Comment: Within a `LineList`, are all the `Numb` without the last three digits the same? What are you suppose to do if they are not?

Comment: This is a *grouping* question. Do a search, it's one of the most often asked questions here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: hi potame, I have validation in SQL for that.

Comment: michael.hor257k - I have and without proper knowldge i could not decipher - the below answer is quite clear though, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**XSL 2.0**

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="//Numb" group-by="substring(.,0,11)">
        <LineNumber><xsl:value-of select="preceding::LineNumber"/>
        </LineNumber>
        <Item>
            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
        </Item>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks, and if im nesting this inbetween other XML elements?

Comment: Your original question and limited sample input and output XML doesn't show the other issues you are describing, which makes it impossible to give an exact answer. Instead of matching "/" change the code to match the parent element.